# main.mok: No such file or directory

Tags: qt

I'm getting error:
main.mok: No such file or directory

when compiling animatedtiles tutorial in QT.
what should I do ??

Comment: Try the following: - to the .pro file, add "HEADERS += main.cpp". From the main.cpp, remove the "#include "main.moc" line.